# Translating WTForms validation error messages

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wtforms

I have a Flask web app with a form like the one below. I know that you can set your custom error messages for validators but how can I do the same for a `DecimalField`? How can I show `'No es un valor decimal válido'` instead of `'Not a valid decimal value'` , for example?

```
class SomeForm(FlaskForm) :
    energy = DecimalField('Energía (kJ)')
```

I tried with: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n/#translating-built-in-messages , but I assume it only works with `wtforms` `Form` and I'm using `FlaskForm` from `flask_wtf`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be some kind of bug with WTForms when you inherit from `FlaskForm` and not from `Form`. Please check here: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/333 I attach the solution for the question example below:

```
class SomeForm(FlaskForm) :
    class Meta:
        locales = ['es_ES', 'es']

        def get_translations(self, form):
            return super(FlaskForm.Meta, self).get_translations(form)

    energy = DecimalField('Energía (kJ)')
```